# Problems using diffmerge mergetool with git

Tags: git, mergetool, difftool

I was trying to resolve some merging conflicts in git using diffmerge, which I just set op on my machine, but it fails and thie error appears:

```
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (diffmerge):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/mergetools/diffmerge: line 136: diffmerge: command not found
merge of nextclue_input.cpp failed
```

Here are the contents of the file the path is pointing at:

```
diff_cmd () {
    "$merge_tool_path" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

merge_cmd () {
    if $base_present
    then
        "$merge_tool_path" --merge --result="$MERGED" \
            "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
    else
        "$merge_tool_path" --merge \
            --result="$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
    fi
    status=$?
}
```

And here is how I setup my .gitconfig file for diffmerge:

```
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = diffmerge --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
    trustExitCode = true
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = diffmerge $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

I don't understand please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely `diffmerge` isn't in %PATH%. Try to specify a full path to the command in `mergetool.diffmerge.cmd` and `difftool.diffmerge.cmd` (`cmd` settings 2nd and 4th sections)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I solved it by putting this in the config file
``
[merge]<br/>
     tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
 cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe  --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
   trustExitCode = true
[diff]
 tool = diffmerge
[difftool "diffmerge"]
 cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE
``